# Condensing functions to go two ways in C++

Tags: c++

Apparently, I should be able to condense these six functions into three simpler functions that go two ways, using bool logic, but I have no idea where to start!

```
void footToMeter(int inputfeet) {
    double outputMeter = ((inputfeet) / (3.281));
    cout << outputMeter;
}

void meterToFoot(int inputmeter) {
    double outputFoot = ((inputmeter)*(3.281));
    cout << outputFoot;
}

void CtoF(int inputC) {
    double outputF = 32 + (inputC*(9.0 / 5.0));
    cout << outputF;
}

void FtoC(int inputF) {
    double outputC = (5.0 / 9)*(inputF - 32);
    cout << outputC;
}

void cMtocF(int inputcM) {
    double outputcF = ((inputcM)*(35.315));
    cout << outputcF;
}

void cFtocM(int inputcF) {
    double outputcM = ((inputcF) / (35.315));
    cout << outputcM;
}
```

Comment: By making a generic convert function, then an enumerate argument specifying whether it is feet-to-metres or the other way around.

Comment: @forthe how would that look? (I'm not sure what you mean by an enumerate argument...sorry)

Comment: An enumerate is basically a type you can define that can take on certain values. An enumerate for colors would look something like this: `enum color {red, yellow, green, blue};`. You can then define a variable with the type `color` and it will be either `red`, `yellow`, `green`, or `blue`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add an extra parameter for each function to determine which direction you want to convert.

Example:

```
void lengthConversion(int inputLength, bool toFeet) 
{
double output;
if (toFeet)
    output = inputLength * 3.281;
else
    output = inputLength / 3.281
cout << output;
}
```

@forthe has a point though - `enum` would make it a bit nicer.

Answer (score 0):

To make it into 3 simpler functions. First try and bundle up the similarities between the current functions:

```
// Put the foot to meter and meter to foot functions into one, with 2 extra boolean values.

void fAndMConversion(int measurement , bool footToMeter , bool meterToFoot) {

   if(footToMeter){
      double fTm = ((measurement) / (3.281));
      cout << fTm;
      }

   if(meterToFoot){
      double mTf = ((measurement)*(3.281));
      cout << mTf;
      }
   }
```

These are the first two functions. This also allows us to get foot to meter and meter to foot conversion in one call to the function: `fAndMConversion(11 , true , true)`. You can bundle it up even further into a `conversions()` function with 7 args in total, 6 being booleans.